# Gracefully close application before installing through Wix managed custom action

Tags: c#, wix, pinvoke, wix3, custom-action

In my WiX installer I want to gracefully close the application that is about to be updated if it is still running. I do not want to prompt the user to close and I do not want to kill the process. I need to have a chance to perform some clean-up etc. before closing the application.

The app is a WinForms app that runs in the system tray. The main form has a title, let's say "mainwindow" for example, but is hidden and has ShowInTaskbar = false.

By playing around with some different tester apps trying `Process.Kill() Process.CloseMainWindow() FindWindow, SendMessage, PostMessage` etc. I have found that the best way for me to do this is to use `PostMessage`

```
var hWnd = FindWindow(null, "mainwindowtitle");
PostMessage(hWnd, WM_CLOSE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
```

That way I can override OnFormClosing and perform any cleanup I need. This works fine from a tester app I threw together. The problem is that it does not work when run in the WiX Installer. I have a c# Custom Action CA.dll and the installer definitely calls the custom action - I can see that from the msiexec logs and if I change the custom action code to just `Process.Kill()` it does stop the app correctly. However when it runs with the `PostMessage` code the application does not close and OnFormClosing never gets called.

Here is my CustomAction code

```
        private const int WM_CLOSE = 0x0010;

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [CustomAction]
    public static ActionResult CloseApplicationGracefully(Session session)
    {
        session.Log("Starting the CloseApplicationGracefully Custom Action - attempting to stop DUC.");

        var hWnd = FindWindow(null, "mainwindowtitle");

        session.Log("Window handle found: " + hWnd);

        bool result = PostMessage(hWnd, WM_CLOSE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);

        session.Log("Result of calling app to close: " + result);

        if (result)
        {
            return ActionResult.Success;
        }
        return ActionResult.Failure;
    }
```

here is the wx setup code

```
<Binary Id="WixCustomAction.dll"
        SourceFile="$(var.WixCustomAction.TargetDir)$(var.WixCustomAction.TargetName).CA.dll" />
<CustomAction Id="WixCustomAction"
              BinaryKey="WixCustomAction.dll"
              DllEntry="CloseDeploymentUpdater" />
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="WixCustomAction" After="FindRelatedProducts"></Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

I have tried calling this custom action in different sequences but no luck...
The code works from a tester app and the custom action works when I use Process.Kill but the code does not work when put in the custom action - must be the sequence of events?

***EDIT***

Using the WixCloseApplications CA as suggested below in a answer results in the following log entries

```
WixCloseApplications:  App: DUC.exe found running, 1 processes, attempting to send close message.
WixCloseApplications:  Sending close message to process id 0x1978
WixCloseApplications:  Result 0x12
WixCloseApplications:  Sending close message to process id 0x1978
WixCloseApplications:  Result 0x0
WixCloseApplications:  Sending close message to process id 0x1978
WixCloseApplications:  Result 0x578
WixCloseApplications:  Sending close message to process id 0x1978
WixCloseApplications:  Result 0x0
.
.
.
MSI (s) (C8!D4) [15:00:47:985]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding WixCloseApplicationsDeferred property. Its value is 'DUC.exe5'.
MSI (s) (C8!D4) [15:00:48:000]: Doing action: WixCloseApplicationsDeferred
.
.
Action 15:00:48: WixCloseApplicationsDeferred. 
Action start 15:00:48: WixCloseApplicationsDeferred.
.
.
Action ended 15:00:48: WixCloseApplicationsDeferred. Return value 1.
Action ended 15:00:48: WixCloseApplications. Return value 1.
```

Comment: Have you tried SendMessage call in the custom action instead of PostMessage?

Comment: @Vijay Sirigiri Yep - I tried SendMessage (using SC_CLOSE) and again this worked in my tester app but not from the WiX installer. Interestingly the EventArgs for OnFormClosing have a CloseReason enum and PostMessage using WM_CLOSE makes it look like the reason is the taskmanager requested the close and a SendMessage with SC_CLOSE makes it look like the User requested the close.

Comment: @rene I can get a valid handle but the result of PostMessage is false so it is not working correctly for some reason. MSDN recommends not using WM_QUIT with PostMessage. I'll try it anyway and see what happens but I suspect the OnFormClosing event will not fire in this case.

Comment: @Peter Kelly can you add a call to GetLastError and log that result?

Comment: @rene GetLastError returning 997 looking that up now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If understand the CloseApp CustomAction from Wix correctly you should enumerate over all windows in a process.

http://wix.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/175af30efe78#src%2fca%2fwixca%2fdll%2fCloseApps.cpp

So you will need to implement an EnumWindows(EnumCallBack, HANDLE processToClose)
And in the EnumCallBack you actually PostMessage WM_CLOSE for each window.

Comment: Helpful pointing to the sourcecode for CloseApp but isn't that what is used by the built-in CA WixCloseApplications ? I have tried that and it closes the application but does not do so gracefully i.e. the OnFormClosing event is not fired.

Comment: @Peter Kelly I was thinking if the MSI was running elevated or not or if the CA was being deffered. Can you post a log? msiexec /i [your msi] /l*vx logfile.log

Comment: @rene I have posted some of the log entries after using util:CloseApplication. What is the impact of deferring?

Comment: Util:CloseApplication sends a WM_CLOSE message to the window of the application you specify.  How that application subclasses that message is that applications problem not WiX's problem.

Comment: @Christoper Painter I am not sure what you mean by "subclasses that message" but if you believe the problem is nothing to do with WiX then why does the custom action work perfectly from a simple tester app but not when called from WiX? Could you suggest another way of doing what I'm trying to achieve? Close a WinForms system tray app gracefully from WiX? Thank!

Comment: From the log file there are two things noticable: 0x12--> No More Files and 0x578 --> ERROR_INVALID_WINDOW_HANDLE. Looks like something is going on because windows that did exist a second ago are now gone? Strange... Can you try to see what happens if you run the app not as an SystemTray application?  Just to rule out that option: your OnFormClosing doesn't touch the e.Cancel?

Comment: no the OnFormClosing doesn't change e.Cancel - it doesn't even get called...I've decided to forget attempting to close the app gracefully and just nuked it with a Process.Kill(). Time is Money.